# InterAtomic Distance between atoms of a molten metal

Tags: atomic-physics, metals, states-of-matter

I was figuring out and researching on interatomic/internuclear distance of metals (particularly Aluminium), but then I started wondering on the difference between magnitudes of interatomic distances in molten metals and that of their solid counterparts. I looked up the web, but couldn't find anything that I could understand. Can someone help me figure out the distance between atoms of Aluminium when it is in its molten state?

Comment: Not much changes when a close-packed solid like aluminium melts: density, resistivity, color, etc.

Comment: Clearly there has to be a volume (density) change upon melting, since it is a first order phase transition. Now your only question is by how much and you can calculate the mean atomic volume and get to the (change in) the mean atomic distance. Or one can look up radial distribution functions of molten metals.

Comment: One reference would be https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11661-017-4053-6, Thermophysical Properties of Liquid Aluminum.

Comment: Thank you everyone! One last question though - How would one figure out the radial distribution function of a molten metal?